# WPF comboboxitem foreground color change

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to change the color of the comboboxitem in wpf, but for some reason it doesn't change and I don't know why.
The items do get loaded I can tell and verify that but i don't see them there not white or black but the same color as the background of the combobox which is kinda gray.

This is what i have to change the comboboxitem color foregournd to black, but does not work.

```
<ComboBox Foreground="#FF000000" x:Name="cBox_nosave" Width="149.8192" Height="22" Canvas.Left="23.7296000000033" Canvas.Top="40.7904000000016">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2, 1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
      </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ComboBox>
```

What do I need to do to change the foreground color to black?
working in wpf .net version 4.6.1

Comment: Do you have some `ComboBox` style defined somewhere? The default foreground of the `ComboBox` is black. No need to set it explicitely to black.

Comment: no, not that i know off, but it's inside a cms and the cms has dark theme

Comment: @TechnologyResearcher: Try to set the `Style` property to `{x:Null}` to apply the default `Style`.

Comment: This seems to be the reason. Setting properties locally on the control (as you did) would've overridden any style settings. So styling may not be the reason. Maybe your theming traverses the visual tree to modify each control's appearance explicitly. How exactly are you theming your application?

Comment: I found my solution but it's really weird one, so apparently when calling the collection for itemssource depending on the list call it was black or either gray

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `TextBlock` foreground in item template

```
<ComboBox Foreground="#FF000000" x:Name="cBox_nosave" Width="149.8192" Height="22" Canvas.Left="23.7296000000033" Canvas.Top="40.7904000000016">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2, 1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
      </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ComboBox>
```